# Getting a "bad interpreter" error when using brew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew

I'm getting this error when I try to run any brew command.

```
Holger-Sindbaeks-MacBook-Air:~ holgersindbaek$ brew help
-bash: /usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have absolutely no idea on how to fix this and been searching for a long time without answer.

Comment: Which OS X? Did you remove your system Ruby?

Comment: Honestly, I can't remember if I removed my system ruby. It's no longer under usr/bin/ruby though. And I'm on Mac OSX 10.6.

Comment: You'll want to re-install it, like from XCode/etc., or install it if it was never there (IIRC it ships with it). It should only be removed if it's replaced with something functionally-equivalent for OS X software that uses it.

Comment: So you are saying I should re-install XCode?

Comment: Possibly; not really sure. You may be able to install just Ruby from it, I really don't recall.

Comment: This solution proposed below has fixed the problem for me:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/23097540/3232673

Answer (score 47, accepted):

What you are getting means that Homebrew has not been able to locate the Ruby interpretter at the specified location.

Install Apple Developer Kit (comes with Xcode) which should be available to you as an optional install (or you can simply download it from Apple). This will install the Ruby interpreter for you.

In case you already have Xcode installed, this means that one of these things is happening:

1. You have a broken Ruby installation
2. You have more than one Ruby installation
3. Your installation has not been configured properly.

To identify if this is the first case, you can run `ruby` and see if you get any response.

If you don't, your installation is broken and you need to reinstall it. If you do, you then run `which ruby`. This should give you the absolute path to your Ruby executable. If this is anything other than `/usr/bin/ruby` then homebrew (and a bunch of other programs) will not be able to find it.

In case you have not ever tampered with your Ruby installation, you can check to see if `/usr/bin/ruby` already exists or not: `cat /usr/bin/ruby`. If you get `No such file or directory`, then you can easily create a symbolic link to your Ruby installation. Assuming the output of `which ruby` to by `/usr/local/bin/ruby`, you create the symbolic link this way: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby` and all should be well.

If there is a file at that location, you can run `file /usr/bin/ruby` to see if it's a real file, a symbolic link, or a corrupted file. If it is a symbolic link, your installation should be working, and since it's not, it probably is either a corrupted symlink or it's a bogus file.

You can remedy that by first deleting it (`sudo rm /usr/bin/ruby`) and then creating a new symlink to the correct location (`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby`).

If non of the above works, you should consult the homebrew team after a clean install of Xcode and removing any traces of a Ruby installation on your system.

**EDIT**

Alternatively, as pointed out by the other answers, the issue might be because of a bad ruby version in your Homebrew settings.

A quick fix might be updating your Homebrew:

```
cd /usr/local
git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

If this does not help, you might want to get your hands dirty and manually fix the problem by:

1. Editing `brew.rb` from `/user/local/Library/brew.rb`
2. Changing `/1.8/` to `/Current/` in the first line, which will cause the hashbang to point to the current Ruby version as the executor

If this does not help, either, you can also modify the `MACOS` check and change it from *10.5* to *10* to avoid the infamous "Homebrew requires Leopard or higher" error.

**DISCLAIMER**

A bunch of thanks to other contributors in the answers below and their commenters. I am not committing plagiarism, simply aggregating the answers into one integrated article to help others.

Comment: But I already have XCode installed, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Run `whereis ruby` and see if you get `/usr/bin/ruby`.

Comment: I can't run whereis ruby, then it doesn't do anything. I can run which ruby and then it gives me "/usr/local/bin/ruby".

Comment: Okay then. Homebrew is looking for it at `/usr/bin/ruby` while it actually is at `/usr/local/bin/ruby`. All you have to do is put a symlink to it at `/usr/bin`. Do this: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: Just tried it and it tells me that "ln: /usr/bin/ruby: File exists". When I try to do brew help after that it gives me the original error.

Comment: There might be a conflict of Ruby versions on your systems. Try the instructions [here](http://linguisticlogic.wordpress.com/2010/11/27/homebrew-mac-osx-and-ruby/)

Comment: That's the guide i followed to get brew installed in the first place.

Comment: So you have Ruby, but the system-wide ruby recognized by the PATH attribute is not the one installed in your `/usr/bin/`. I think you can change that by editing the place where Homebrew looks up for the Ruby installation.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm currently looking into it.

Comment: Can you do me one favor, and run these two commands and give me the results: `/usr/bin/ruby -v` and `/usr/local/bin/ruby -v`

Comment: And also, have you tried [RVM on Mac](http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2011/07/30/installing-rails-on-os-x-lion-with-homebrew-rvm-and-mysql/)?

Comment: With /usr/bin/ruby -v it says: -bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
With /usr/local/bin/ruby -v it says: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
I already have RVM... does that make a difference?

Comment: This means that there is NO Ruby installation at `/usr/bin`, but there is a file system pointer there. Could you tell me if `file /usr/bin/ruby` returns the architecture for this binary file?

Comment: /usr/bin/ruby: broken symbolic link to /opt/local/bin/ruby
 returns: /usr/bin/ruby: broken symbolic link to /opt/local/bin/ruby

Comment: Okay. As I suspected, you have followed those instructions without adapting them to your own situation. Run `sudo rm -f /usr/bin/ruby` ro get rid of the broken link, and then run `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby` to make the proper link to your installation of Ruby.

Comment: You are welcome. :) I now have to edit the answer to incorporate the comments into it. Thanks for being responsive and not leaving your question off for a week. I hope you can someday find the time to come back here and help out other users.

Comment: Okay, just edited the answer. Please see if it describes the solution correctly.

Comment: That described the problem and solution very well. I'll do my best to contribute, but I'm still very new to RoR and I really think it's got a steep learning curve.

Comment: Don't worry, you'll get on pretty quickly, once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Thanks for the confidence :-).

Comment: Sorry for the downvote but I think the answer should be more readable/concise, given how simple the answer below is. On my system it worked and I don't consider my Ruby installation broken, it has just been updated. (1., 2., 3. might therefore be confusing)

Comment: @Philip I don't think that many people come back and update the answer to the needs of everyone. My answer and procedure worked perfectly for the asking user, and you can follow that through the comments. I have even gone beyond that and incorporated all the other answers into my own, while adding disclaimers. I do consider you down vote a misconduct.

Answer (score 65):

I got this error (much the same):

> /usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
>   /usr/local/bin/brew: line 26: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0

and fixed by the solution below:

1. Open `brew.rb`:

   ```
   $ sudo vim /usr/local/Library/brew.rb
   ```
2. Change the first line's `1.8` to `Current`:

   Before:

   ```
   #!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -W0
   ```

   After:

   ```
   #!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0
   ```

Then `brew` works for me. Hope it helps if any other one got this issue. :)

---

If you get the error

> Homebrew requires Leopard or higher. For Tiger support, see:
>   https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew

change the MACOS check from `<10.5` to `<10`.

Tip by @TimCastelijns:

> 10.5 doesn't work because in comparison, it's higher than 10.10 (.1 vs .5). I added a check (`and MACOS_VERSION != 10.10`) instead of lowering from 10.5 to 10.

Comment: Great! Fixed my problem after updating to Yosemite.

Comment: when I make the changes you suggest, I get the error Homebrew requires Leopard or higher. For Tiger support, see:
https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew

Comment: I'm getting the same result as @scientiffic whilst I'm running Yosemite

Comment: @TimReynaert same result? his error is "requires Leopard or higher", if ur system is Yosemite, how come this error happen? :S

Comment: There is a comment on this page that talks about changing the /usr/local/Library/brew.rb file to:
a) update the version of ruby as mentioned in the answer above
b) change the MACOS check to use 10 and not 10.5 (looks like 10.10 is causing problems)

I did that, did a brew update, and all seems to be well now.

Comment: 10.5 doesn't work because in comparison, it's higher than 10.10 (.1 vs .5). I added a check (`and MACOS_VERSION != 10.10`) instead of lowering from 10.5 to 10

Comment: @TimCastelijns it's interesting, i've updated the answer to append ur tip , thx :)

Comment: Still is true in 2018 when installing fastlane with homebrew

Answer (score 30):

Fix:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 9):

At the risk of oversimplifying things, try running

```
gem install bundler
```

I was transitioning my Ruby environment from RBENV to RVM and it worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

This happened because I needed to update brew - in the updated version it already uses Current ruby

```
cd /usr/local
git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

This solved the problem

Comment: I added your points to my answer above. Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: This worked for me thanks, I had to use  `sudo` for the the pull.

Comment: You shouldnt need to use sudo, i think brew doctor will fix the permissions for you now that youve got it running

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the path for Ruby.Framework

I solved it with commands as mentioned.

1. `brew install cocoapods --build-from-source`
2. `brew link --overwrite cocoapods`

If you have a lower version below `Xcode 11`, you have to remove it before you use the above commands.

Reference: [Ruby Framework issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8955)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, so I kept browsing and found this answer, 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24225960/1359088
which did fix brew for me. He says in step 1 to install XCode 6 command line tools, but doesn't say how; use this command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when updated to MacOSX High Sierra & using Xcode 9 with that. High Sierra update ruby gem to version 2.3 but xcpreety command of Xcode 9 still using Ruby 2.0 which is unable to find now & gives bad interpreter.
Just go to Terminal & run

```
sudo gem install xcpretty
```

Restart Xcode & do fresh clean build it works for me.
Hope it helps!!!

Comment: I have no idea why you were downvoted but your answer helped me, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to macOS High Sierra, get it fixed with following commands:

sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

In my case seems like `fastlane` installed incorrectly with `brew install fastlane` system didn't write correct path to fastlane. I fixed it with `alias fastlane=~/.fastlane/bin/fastlane`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with commands as mentioned.

1.) Uninstall your GEM.

`gem unistall GEM`

2.) Then Install your GEM.

`sudo gem install GEM -n /usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

I got `bad interpreter: No such file or directory` error when used `xcpretty` and `xcpretty-travis-formatter` on upgraded MacOS.

To solve it

```
gem install xcpretty
gem install xcpretty-travis-formatter
```

That is why I can recommend you to reinstall failed component `gem install <name>`

```
#For example error looks like
/usr/local/bin/xcpretty-travis-formatter: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

#use
gem install xcpretty-travis-formatter
```