# /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, homebrew

When I enter `brew doctor` (or any `brew` command) in my terminal, I get this as a response:

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/brew: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I have seen the `^M` response before and I think it has to do with dos line ending files. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This happened to me, and I figured out why.  I had copied my .gitconfig over from my windows machine, and didn't change the core.autocrlf to input before installing brew.  D'oh!  I think Javier Roca's solution is the nicest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [./configure : /bin/sh^M : bad interpreter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script: bad interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2841593/608639)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I don't know how carriage returns ended up in your brew file, but you can remove them using `dos2unix` or by piping it through `tr -d '\r'`.

Example:

```
tr -d '\r'  < /usr/local/bin/brew   > myfixedbrew
```

Once verified, you can use

```
mv myfixedbrew /usr/local/bin/brew && chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/brew
```

to replace the old one.

Comment: How would I use tr -d '\r'? Should I cd to /usr/local/bin then use it on the brew file?

Comment: @mah wouldn't I need to use brew to install dos2unix?

Comment: Hrm. Sorry, I didn't realize dos2unix wasn't already on OS X.

Comment: Ok @thatotherguy I used that command and now I am coming up with a new error: "sudo: brew: command not found". I am thinking about removing all brew then installing it again but I get this:"bash: /usr/local/bin/brew: Permission denied" when I try to delete it using: "sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup"

Comment: @TheWaller I neglected to mention that you'd have to add back execute permissions on the file

Comment: Thank you, finally I could install brew

Comment: this happened to me too all i did is run  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
 from terminal as instructed

Comment: That fixes it. It seems the Ruby install script causes this issue on Mac OS X (just tried on Yosemite)

Comment: awesome that fixed it.

Comment: Bless on you, you helped me out. That was such a strange an uncomfortable issue for me

Comment: After how many decades of carriage return & line feed debates, why do we still have interpreters that even care about the difference!?

Answer (score 40):

This worked for me:

1. Open file /usr/local/bin/brew with vi (`vi /usr/local/bin/brew`)
2. While on vi issue this commad (via esc or :) `:set fileformat=unix`
3. Close file on vi via `:wq!`

The brew command should be OK now.

Regards.

Comment: This issue drove me insane, this solution however worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: brilliant -- way simpler as well :-)

Answer (score 2):

For people using Intellij, open the `gradlew` file of your project. In the lower right corner of the IDE there will be one element written `CRLF` or `LF` or `CR`. Changed it to `LF` and it worked. (I'm using Windows+WSL)

Comment: could you clarify your answer? there appears to be a mistake -  `LR` is not a valid line ending. thanks!

Comment: Hum, I think it is a typo. Updating the answer to `LF`. Thanks!