# Homebrew on Mac OS X (El Capitan): syntax error near unexpected token `{

Tags: macos, bash, syntax, installation, homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew on OS X El Capitan.

I used the following command to install Homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

So far it worked. But then if I tried to run any brew command, for example:

```
brew help
```

I got the error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/brew: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

So I tried both top answers of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097528/bin-shm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory) (which sets the file format of brew to unix). Now, whatever brew command I run (e.g. brew doctor or brew help), I get:

```
: command not foundbrew.sh: line 2: 
'usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `{
'usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 3: `odie() {
```

How do I fix this syntax error so I'm finally able to use Homebrew? Thanks in advance for any advice!

EDIT: Clarifying.

Comment: You might want to report this to the Brew maintainers, either to find out what you did wrong (seemingly nothing), or to report this as a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^M` usually means `\r` as in `\r\n` which is windows line endings.

You should try to open `/usr/local/bin/brew` and save it with unix line endings or use the command line to `dos2unix` to do the job for you:

```
dos2unix /usr/local/bin/brew
```

You might encounter other files with the same problem, eg: `usr/local/Library/brew.sh`

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that. Change the fileformat of brew.sh also to unix fixed it. Thanks!