# Syntax error while executing any brew command

Tags: homebrew

```
Error:
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token '<<<'
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 1: '<<<<<<< 61ffa47gd9dc179ddff792db1dc6f55464f6c16b'
```

I tried removing and adding closing triangular brackets but neither one worked for me.

I found some similar questions/answers related to this where unexpected token was ')', but they didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unresolved git conflict. Run the following command and you’ll be fine:

```
cd /usr/local && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be similar issue than [Homebrew on Mac OS X (El Capitan): syntax error near unexpected token `{](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230256/homebrew-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token)

`dos2unix /usr/local/bin/brew`

Comment: I downvoted because it has nothing to do with the other issue and running `dos2unix` won’t fix anything here.