# How can I avoid CRs in files in Git/IntelliJ on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, carriage-return, linefeed

I'm getting the `/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` I know there are multiple posts for this as seen here:

[/bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097528/bin-shm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/304999/not-able-to-execute-a-sh-file-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter

[How to change line-ending settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418975/how-to-change-line-ending-settings)

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

I'm devloping on a windows machine and trying to run on a Linux machine. 
I've tried the following:
`git config --global core.autocrlf true` in intellij terminal
Setting `LF` on the bottom right of the intellij screen

Still getting same error. 
i'm sorry about reposting, can't find any other fixes?

GIT: https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex-API/blob/master/scripts/runapp.sh
Thanks

Comment: Try `man dos2unix`.

Comment: I’m deploying to an AWS EC2, so I’ll need to run that new script on the existing scripts that are already in git?

Comment: Good luck. Next time try to express that in the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can create script file using `vi`, `touch`, `nano` in Linux, don't create file in Windows.