# Bad interpreter error when running Brew commands

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I get the following error when I try to use `brew` commands.

> zsh: /usr/local/bin/brew: bad interpreter:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin: no
>   such file or directory

I found a [few threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864668/getting-a-bad-interpreter-error-when-using-brew) that recommend changing the first line on the following `/usr/local/Library/brew.rb` file from...

`#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -W0`

to...

`#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0`

The issue is that I don't have the `brew.rb` file in that directory.

Do I need to create the `brew.rb` file and add `#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0`?

FYI - The file `/usr/local/bin/brew`contains

`#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -W0`

but if I change it to

`#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby -W0`

and then run the `brew` command I get the following error...

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:191: invalid
>   multibyte escape: /^\037\213/ (SyntaxError) invalid multibyte escape:
>   /^\037\235/ invalid multibyte escape: /^\xFD7zXZ\x00/     from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:2:in `<top
>   (required)>'  from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'     from /usr/local/bin/brew:17:in`'

Any idea?

Thanks lot

Comment: I would try reinstalling brew.  Sounds like something in its configuration is messed up and that could be the easiest solution, if it works.  Hopefully it wouldn't remove any of the installed software though.

Comment: Also, have you run `brew doctor`?  And `brew update`?

Comment: So reinstalling homebrew would be the best solution? I'm just afraid to loose installed software, git etc. FYI - Running `brew doctor` or brew update I also get an error.