# Capistrano user denied permission

Tags: rvm, capistrano, centos7

I'm working on **Centos7** server with **Capistrano version 3.7.2**.

My problem is about executing the command "`cap -v`" by not root user. The error reporting is this:

[Image reporting_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuxM1.png)

I know that it is a problem with folder permissions but I don't know what folder.

The folder `/usr/bin/ruby` exist and it has permissions for all users.

The file `/usr/local/bin/cap` is good declared.

[Image file /usr/local/bin/cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcuSK.png)

For the root user it works correctly but for other users it does not

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864668/getting-a-bad-interpreter-error-when-using-brew

Comment: In my case for user root "cap -v" working correct but with the user webdepint it does not work.